# Is $out functionality available in aggregate function in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

```
pipe=[{'$match':{'site_id':22462}},{'$out':"site_new"}]
db.site.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
```

The above code throws an error "OperationFailure: exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$out'"

Comment: What MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: Fixed it with an updated version of MongoDB. Thanks!